# Zoom on Image relative position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I need to zoom and pinch on a  scrollView and the image on it should be on the same relative position, like Google Maps.

Does anybody know the formula for that?

My code so far;

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat){
    //print(scale);
    self.placePointers(scale: scale)

}



func placePointers(scale: CGFloat)
{
    for imageViews in PDFView.scrollView.subviews
    {
        if(imageViews is UIImageView){
          imageViews.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }

    let xAs = ((scale * CGFloat(300)) - PDFView.scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    let yAs = ((scale * CGFloat(300)) - PDFView.scrollView.contentOffset.y)

    let rect = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(x: xAs, y: yAs),
        size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
    print(PDFView.scrollView.contentScaleFactor);

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: rect)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pin_afgerond.png");
    PDFView.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

}
```

Comment: What is "the same relative position"? Zooming can involve scrolling; do you intend to disable that?

Comment: When you scroll, zoom or pan. The image placed on the scrollview should remain on the same location on the scrollview and not the view